# sshd stopped accepting external requests

Tags: ssh

EDIT: I dont seem to get an error from the rpi, well it ignores the request as for as I can see

```
grep sshd /var/log/auth.log
```

says

```
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22
```

I have been using ssh to login to my rpi for quite some time, now when I try login it times out.
I can ping the rpi ip address from remote site and when I am logged into rpi can ssh locally
If I run in verbose mode from the client to the rpi I get the following (Quite long sorry)

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.34 [192.168.1.34] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/peter/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/peter/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/peter/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/peter/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/peter/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/peter/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/peter/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/peter/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1     Debian-4+deb7u1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.1.34" from file  "/home/peter/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file   /home/peter/.ssh/known_hosts:13
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert- v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-   cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2- nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange- sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie- hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-  sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert- v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh- ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert- v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh- ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256- ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256- gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish- cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256- ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256- gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish- cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1- etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256- etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160- etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-  md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2- 512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256- etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160- etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac- md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2- 512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2- nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange- sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192- cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
Connection closed by 192.168.1.34
```

Comment: I presume by your comments that you are logged in as a user and not as root. I did notice that the recent firmware had blocked root SSH access. Good practice depending on the application. But had me head scratching for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem has been fixed, not a satisfying answer but here is what I did

1) Purged and removed the ssh server

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove openssh-server
```

2) Updated the firmware

```
sudo rpi-update
```

3) Updated and then upgraded and reinstalled ssh server

```
sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude upgrade && sudo aptitude install openssh-server
```

This is a brute force fix but the effort of trying to catch the bug was more effort than worth to me (Many would disagree)